# how to find the ?

Tags: real-analysis

Given $\epsilon >0$, what is the largest $\delta >0$ which fits the definition of continuity of the function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
    \frac{x+3}{2},& \text{if } x \leq 1\\
    \frac{7-x}{3}, &\text{if } x\geq 1\\
    \end{cases}$$

what is the largest $\delta$ which fits the definition of continuity of the function

at $x=1.$ that is, the largest $δ > 0$ for which the implication $|x − 1| < δ$ ⇒
$|f(x) − f(1)| <  ε $ holds?

My  solution : For $x<1$: $|f(x)-f(1)|=|\frac{x+3}{2}-2|=\frac{1}{2}|x-1| <ε, |x-1|< 2ε $

and

for $x>1$: $|f(x)-f(1)|=|\frac{7-x}{3}-2|=\frac{1}{3}|x-1| < ε,|x-1|< 3ε$.

ANSWER :   the largest $\delta $ will be  $2ε$

Is  my answer is right  or  wrong ??

Pliz checks  it  and correct  me  if i have done wrong

Comment: Your answer is right.

Comment: thanks  a lots @ jose carlos santos

Comment: You're right but why the point $f(x=1)$ is defined twice?

Comment: @Niing: twice $f(1):=2$ is harmless.

Comment: @Niing see  as  x>1  and x <1   so   i  write  twice

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks

Comment: @henry: you missed Ning's legitimate question.

Comment: im not getting@YvesDaoust

Comment: Niing's question is legitimate, but the set of possible answers is obvious: the person setting the question either thought it was a helpful instance of redundancy, or doesn't have as strong negative feelings about redundancy as you do, or didn't intend any redundancy at all but made a mistake. In any case, this isn't an interesting question mathematically, and I don't see any reason to hold the OP to account for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

With the change of variable $t:=x+1$,

$$f(t-1)=2+\begin{cases}
    \ \ \ \dfrac t2,& \text{if } t \leq 0\\
    -\dfrac t3, &\text{if } t\geq 0\\
    \end{cases}$$

it becomes obvious that $2\epsilon$ and $3\epsilon$ will do, and the smallest of the two is the strongest constraint.

Comment: thanks @Yves Daoust